# I got error with graphql resolver in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql

i'am trying to use graphql currently but i got this error
(Cannot return null for non-nullable field Person.name.)
I have tried to fix it but i couldn't plz help me

**App.js**

```
import resolvers from './graphql/resolvers';

const app = express();
const Router = express.Router();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));



app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    rootValue: resolvers,
    graphiql: true
}));



export default app;
```

**schema.js**

```
import { buildSchema } from 'graphql';

const schema = buildSchema(`
    type Person {
        name: String!
        age: Int!
        gender: String!
    }

    type Query {
        people: [Person]!
        person(id: Int!): Person
    }
`);

export default schema;
```

**resolvers.js**

```
import { people, getById } from '../fakedb';

const resolvers = {
    Query {
        people: () => people,
        person: (_, { id }) => getById(id)
    } 
export default Query;
```

**fakedb.js**

```
    export const people = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Andy",
        age: 23,
        gender: "male"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Nam",
        age: 26,
        gender: "female"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Jang",
        age: 21,
        gender: "male"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Duk",
        age: 23,
        gender: "male"
    }
];

export const getById = id => {
    const filteredPeople = people.filter(person => person.id === id);
    return filteredPeople[0];
};
```

I checked my db.js a lot of times, but i don't think it has a problem
I am thinking the error comes from other place
but i can't find it
Would anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: Please include the POST request / graphql query you are making that causes the error

Comment: Your *resolvers.js*  is missing a closing `};` and should be doing `export default resolvers;` instead of `export default Query;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to have any issues, but are you running a query for the ids which are present in the fakedb people array?
Please share the query you are passing with id.